# My localhost doesn't refresh, it only refreshes when I restart my computer

Tags: node.js, server, terminal, localhost

I am hosting a node.js file using the terminal on my Mac:

```
cd /Users/bobboekel/Desktop/Exploration
node /Users/bobboekel/Desktop/Exploration/myfirst.js
```

Now when I enter in Safari: http://localhost:8080
It will load the file. Yet when I update the file, the page doesn't refresh – Neither when I refresh the window, restart the browser or open it in another browser. I have not managed to refresh the localhost except for restarting the Mac. Anyone have a clue?

Comment: Ctrl+C to quit the process and then use the node command again, or use something like nodemon

Comment: You need to restart node app not browser

Comment: Or set up your development environment with a browser sync that doesn't require restarting server for every edit

Comment: So you've written an HTTP server using Node.js and it doesn't behave the way you expect. We can't do much about it, because you haven't shown us a [mcve] of your server's source code.

Comment: The second line in your code is funny :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nodejs evaluates code and caches it, and never reloads it till you restart the server. To avoid all the hustle of quiting in terminal then restating again, you can use [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever). It can start, restart, stop and list currently running servers. It can also watch for changing files and restart node as needed.

- You can install it using: `npm install forever -g`,
- Then call the forever command using the -w flag to watch file for changes (`forever -w ./my-script.js`),
- Or you can watch a whole direcory for file changes and restart the server whenever: (`forever --watch --watchDirectory ./dir/to/watch  ./path/to/myfirst.js`)

After installing `forever`, the equivalent of your code is like below:

```
cd /Users/bobboekel/Desktop/Exploration
forever --watch --watchDirectory ./ myfirst.js
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that would work, yet, after doing your first bullet:  Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' Do you have a quick solution?

Comment: nice to know it got resolved

Comment: I fixed the permissions, thanks a lot! Now I can continue working on my social medium :-) (Don't worry I know html css jquery and sql, just learning node.js)

Comment: @B.VanBoekel welcome